# How to extract a part of a JSON String from an SQL string Base64

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml, base64

**Situation:**

I have a column of encoded Base64 strings that I would like to decode and extract a specific part of it. It seems the decoded value is in `JSON` format (not familiar with `JSON` at all)

**Objective:**

How can I extract the value of a dictionary part of a JSON string.

**Current query:**

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("BASE64_COLUMN"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')) AS RESULT
FROM
    (SELECT [value] AS BASE64_COLUMN FROM #test1) as testtable
```

**Output:**

The output looks like this:

```
RESULT
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}
```

**Desired Output:**
How can i extract the value of the first dictionary: 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like we don't have all the pieces here, but, using that JSON string you can get the value for the key `'a'` by simply using `OPENJSON`:

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}';

SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
WHERE [key] = 'a';
```

I, of course, am assuming you are using SQL Server 2016. Otherwise SQL Server does not support JSON parsing, and you'll be better using an application to do so.

For 2014-, if you just want the first node's value then you could do

```
SELECT V.JSON, SUBSTRING([JSON],CHARINDEX(':',[JSON])+1,CHARINDEX(',',[JSON])-(CHARINDEX(':',[JSON])+1))
FROM (VALUES(@JSON))V([JSON]);
```

So, for a blind guess against your table (as I can't test):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([JSONString],CHARINDEX(':',[JSONString])+1,CHARINDEX(',',[JSONString])-(CHARINDEX(':',[JSONString])+1))
FROM (SELECT [value] AS BASE64_COLUMN FROM #test1) as testtable
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("BASE64_COLUMN"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')))V(JSONString);
```

This **assumes** that every string from your expression contains both *at least* 1 `:` character and `,` character. If it dosen't, then we need more (representative) sample data.

Comment: Unfortunately using v2014. Additionally,  I would like to parse the whole column

Comment: What do you mean "the whole column"? And saying you're using SQL Server 2014 is a very important part of thus "puzzle" @RogerSteinberg

Comment: I have a column with thousands of encoded strings that I want to decode, not just a value. sql-server tag is included in my question @larnu

Comment: Sorry, I mean saying you're using SQL Server 2014 is important (as support for JSON was added then). So, are you saying that the (small) sample you've given us isn't representative of your actual data here @RogerSteinberg? If so you need to improve your question to be representative; but that doesn't change that SQL Server 2014 does not parse JSON natively.

Comment: it is representative. wasn't even aware that there were an OpenJson function specifically used for this

Comment: So, apart from that this is a 2016+ answer, why would this not work? You haven't therefore explain what "the whole column" means. If `1` isn't the "correct" answer here, what is..?

Comment: your answer extracts the value of a single row observation correct? If so the correct answer should extract the value associated to "a" of each row into a new column.what solution would work for a 2014 version ?

Comment: No, the above are set based solutions. I just but the value in a variable as I don't have access to your table. The variable could be replaced with a column, or expression, @RogerSteinberg. So instead `FROM OPENJSON(SomeColumnName)` or `SUBSTRING(SomeColumnName)`. Personally, for the latter, I would put the expression in the `VALUES` clause instead though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how permanent/clean this solution is (in fact it's quite ugly), and in most cases, you should reconsider using json-encoded strings for these values or parse it in an application as @Larnu suggests.  In any case, you could use [PATINDEX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms188395(v=sql.90)) and [SUBSTRING()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) to get the first value:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING (
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("BASE64_COLUMN"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')),
        6,
        PATINDEX(
            '%,"b":%',
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("BASE64_COLUMN"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)'))
        ) -6
    )
FROM
    (SELECT [value] AS BASE64_COLUMN FROM #test1) as testtable;
```

Comment: getting invalid length parameter passed  to the substring function

Comment: @RogerSteinberg see edit.  I missed a comma after the massive convert/cast/etc line.